# Brood War Multiplayer Maps

Tags: starcraft

I'm going to have a Brood War LAN party and may end up playing some team games, mostly just teams of 2.

Are there any map packs for Brood War with maps similar to Starcraft 2 where team start positions are close/connected?

Thank you.

Comment: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Category:Maps_%282v2%29

Comment: Note that maps with connected bases were extremely uncommon in Brood War. Though the listed maps were used in 2v2 play professionally, I can't recall any of them with connected mains.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about map recommendations.

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic since it is asking for maps with start positions close by, and is about a video game.

Answer (score 1):

Well, shucks.  If this question is acceptable here, then it should be answered even if it is four years old.

I know of one such map which has been available since September 2010.  The name is Greater Chucktropolis, and it has 8 spawn locations.  Layout makes it good for 4v4, but the connected bases can support 2v2v2v2 at most.  So, you could do 2v2 and have a total of 4 bases.  The spawn locations are near enough to share defenses in those pairs.
I've only messed around on it with the computer players, so I can't say that I've tested it at all.  The designer is the same person who did Chex Quest, if that means anything to you.

http://www.chucktropolis.com/gamers.htm
Direct link:  http://www.chucktropolis.com/downloads/%288%29Greater%20Chucktropolis.scm

I hope the LAN party went well.